# Where did the idea for the approach to solving this boundary layer problem come from?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, viscosity, navier-stokes

I found the derivation of Blasius-Equations [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw6aQJGD3FU): A free stream velocity hits a flat plate and the goal is to derive boundary layer behavior.

Everything in this tutorial is clear - but the most interesting point has not been answered:

How do I get an idea about how the **similarity parameter** shall be chosen? And why is the **non-dimensional stream function** defined as it is?

[image]

In the end, after a complicated calculation, we end up with a very simple ordinary differential equation in $\eta $ in which everything beside f cancels out (including x).

[image]

This equation can easily be solved numerically. But how can I know in advance that choosing exactly these $\eta$ and $f(\eta)$ would lead me to this simple thing? In the end I'm pretty frustrated because even though I understood every step, I feel like I wouldn't have gotten to it in a thousand years...

Is this pure intuition of a genius or can I somehow learn that shown methodology?